# Create Workflow to update a column in a library and a list

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a column called "TMD". This data is already populated in a list (We will call it List1).  I would like to somehow have a workflow populate the data of the TMD column in a Library and another list.

I have added the TMD column to my document library already and my List2. Now I just need something to reference List1 and copy the "TMD" column to my library and list2.

I'm using share point 2013.

Comment: are you need this for new items in list 1 or old items ?

Comment: So mike does data already exists in List1 which you wish to copy  or new data will be entered and you need a workflow to update this data in List2 and Library?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a workflow at `list 1` to add update a list field in `list 2` and `library` as the following :

- Open SharePoint Designer
- Go to workflow , from the above ribbon , select List workflow and select your list (List 1)
- From the above ribbon , select `Update List Item` action

[image]

- click on this list and select you List (List 2)

[image]

- Because of you select other list / library you should set which item should be updated , so you should have a specific key that references your item at the second list from the first list at **Find the list Item** Section.
- Then click Add to select `TMD field` and set its value the value from the current list by click on **fx** button.

[image]

- Again , create a new `Update List Item` for Library 2,
- save and publish your workflow.

**Note:** don't forget to set workflow run om item created or changed