# Validation IF Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, formula, list-validation

I am stuck on a validation column, I need **Date Effective From** mandatory if **Approval Status** is equal to Approved and vice versa I need **Approval Status** mandatory if **Date Effective From** is not blank.

I have the below code which works if status is approved and no date is entered.

```
=IF([Approval Status]="Approved", AND([Date Effective From]<>""), TRUE)
```

How do I go adding also the condition vice versa that if the users enters the date the status must be changed to Approved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set the Status to "Approved" using formula, But you can mandate users to select Approved status using below formula:

```
=IF([Approval Status] = "Approved", IF([Date Effective From] <> "", TRUE, FALSE), IF([Date Effective From] <> "", FALSE, TRUE))
```

Additionally, you can show error message to users as per your requirements (Something like: "Status should be Approved if Effective date is Entered OR Enter Effective date if Status is Approved").

Comment: Thanks this is what I was trying to achieve!

Comment: Great, glad it helped you. Please [Upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that it will help others with similar question in future.

Answer (score 0):

**If the users enter the date the status must be changed to Approved?**

You can't set a field value using the validation formula. Instead, you should use Workflow that runs on Item Update and Add, to [update the list item if the date value is not null!](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/198483/create-workflow-to-update-a-column-in-a-library-and-a-list)

[image]

[image]

> See Also, [SharePoint Designer Workflow check if the date field is empty](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/check-if-a-date-field-is-null-or-empty-in-sharepoint-designer-workflow/)

Answer (score 0):

The column validation only affects the column it belongs to. Would you like to provide examples about your further plan?

If Momahed gets you right, then you will need to use tools like workflow/flow to update the value of Approval status column. Column validation does not support updating fields. It only set rules on the value user fill in.

Or are you trying to create a new validation rule for the approval status column?

Comment: I am trying to achieve this via the Validation Settings, basically if the users edit the drop down column to approved they must enter a date in the effective columns and this works perfectly with the validation settings I have entered, What I also want is that if the users enter a date in the effective column and they forget to change the status to approved then the validation rule kicks is as for first case.