# Calculate Column Based On Self (Circular Reference Workaround)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column-formula

I have a date and time data type calculated column named "Date of Review" with the following formula:

```
=IF([Status]<>"Select",NOW(),"")
```

Formula explained, if the choice column "Status" has a value other than "Select", the "Date of Review" column will be populated with NOW(), in effect creating a timestamp for when the status was changed.

The problem is any time the record is edited, the "Date of Review" refreshes to NOW().

I understand that you can't use ISBLANK() but I understand I could compare the current value of the column to another.

With that, I created a column "EmptyDate" that is not on any form and is always blank.

What I am trying to do is something like this, but I don't know what I am missing:

```
=IF([Date Of Review]=[Empty Date],(IF([Status]<>"Select",NOW(),""),"")
```

I can't get it to work.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For recording the time when the status change, I will suggest you to use a flow. You cannot do a self reference in calculated column, but you can add an if condition in flow to check the `Date of Review` column. Only update the field value when it is empty. Remember to input the null value in the expression like [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Flow-Condition-If-Field-is-Blank/td-p/91665/page/2).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As you have mentioned in **tags**, you are using `SharePoint Enterprise`, so in such a case, you can't use Microsoft Automate (Flow) in a SharePoint On-Premise environment that doesn't have an `on-premises data gateway` installed.

So in this case, Instead of using a calculated column, you have to use SharePoint Designer Workflow to do the following:

- Create a workflow that runs on item add or update
- Add If condition to check if [the date field is empty or not](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/check-if-a-date-field-is-null-or-empty-in-sharepoint-designer-workflow/) and the status column value is `"Select"`
- If the above condition is met, so add the `update the list item` action to update the date value with today.

[image]

**Check also**

- [update the list item if the date value is null!](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/198483/create-workflow-to-update-a-column-in-a-library-and-a-list)
- [Supported and Unsupported Columns In SharePoint Calculated Column Formula](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/supported-fields-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/#unsupported-columns-in-sharepoint-calculated-column-formula)
- [Install Workflow Manager for SharePoint 2016/2019](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/configure-workflow-manager-sharepoint-2016/)