# Auto-Populate Date in Column When Seperate Column Gets Filled

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, date, syntax, auto-populate

I've checked around a few other questions asked around this, but none have really applied to what I am looking for.

Using Sharepoint 2019 Online, we have a sheet that contains 12 different columns. What we want to do, is when someone puts in a number for "PO #" column, that "Date PO Issued" field automatically fill with todays date. This way we can avoid empty fields when accounting is entering info.

I've been toying with a few different calculated values, but none seem to be working. Is calculated value the place for this to be done? Can it even be done?

This is what I came up with for adding todays date

`=DATE(YEAR(Today),MONTH(Today),DAY(Today))`

Then tried to add on that to depend on column 2, which is titled PO #. None of these seemed to be proper syntax

`=ISNUMBER([Col2])DATE(YEAR(Today),MONTH(Today),DAY(Today))`

`(IF([Column 2]="PO #",TEXT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yyyy"))`

I appreciate it. Fairly new to administrating sharepoint, so still learning everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this with JavaScript on a Script Editor.
Let me know if you aren't familiar with JavaScript; i can post some sample coding.

PS: Just saw that this was SharePoint online so won't work unless Script Editor has  been enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest not using calculated column as it is not intended to handle a event triggered task. A formula like `=IF([PO #]<>"",NOW(),"")` may display the time. However everything user edited the item the calculated column will be updated with the current time, which I assume is not the expected behavior.

For SharePoint 2019, I will assume you do not have access to Power Automate(Flow), so the standard way will be using a workflow to update the item column when the item is created or modified. Check if the `"PO #"` column is empty , then update the `"Date PO Issued"` with the current date. To do that you will need to download [SharePoint designer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491) and create a custom workflow. Here is an similar thread which you can take as reference:[Create Workflow to update a column in a library and a list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/198483/create-workflow-to-update-a-column-in-a-library-and-a-list)

Comment: Appreciate your feedback, and letting me know "Calculated Column" isn't the way to go, so I can stop going down that rabbit hole.

I started to look into creating a workflow in Sharepoint Designer, and found something strange. On the web portion of this document, it has different columns than what is showing in Sharepoint Desginer.

[Sharepoint Designer](https://i.imgur.com/Gllbj5r.png)

But in the sharepoint web, it has Date PO Issued which is what I need

[Sharepoint Online](https://i.imgur.com/Egp4HGG.png)

I will keep looking into this on my end to try and learn more.